# Windows 10 : install ssh failed

Tags: ssh, powershell

I go through Windows PowerShell to install OpenSSH Client and Server . When it comes to executing ssh commands, that gives exception insteadh of a list of options for user to choose
[image]
Would you please tell me what other steps do i need to finish the installation  ?

Comment: I just installed a `posh-ssh` module, if that helps.  (can't figure out how to use it, but it's installed.....)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `path` to `OpenSSH` is properly set inside `PATH` environment variable. The installation should have done it automatically, but do confirm it. It ought to be

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\
```

or could be

```
C:\Program Files\OpenSSH
```

..depending on which version of OpenSSH you have installed.

If this is not set in `PATH`, just add the correct path to it, and that should correct the issue.

Some older versions of Windows OpenSSH also required a `sign-out` and `sign-in` or a restart, so in case the above does not help, try this as well.